# why do we have to create a load balancer in order to add a self-signed certificate to an EC2 instance (to enable SSL)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a self-signed certificate to be added for my EC2 instances. After reading docs, I realized that I have to create a load balancer first to enable https on instances.
What's the exact role of the load balancer here?
From now on should I always use the load balancer's address or the elastic IP address of the instance to access that instance?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to setup a load balancer to enable SSL for a service running on an ec2 instance.

The "classic" HA setup on AWS includes a ec2 instances in an auto-scaling group behind a load balancer. In such a scenario the SSL certificate would be setup on the load balancer.

If you are running only one ec2 instance there is no need to setup a load balancer to setup ssl. You can just attach the elastic ip to the ec2 instance and setup SSL on the ec2 instance. The normal configuration steps apply than.